# Missing text in compiler output

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have a working combined Java/C++ app which I'm developing with eclipse. I think (correct me if you think I'm wrong) that it uses some version of GCC to compile the C++ parts. When I ask eclipse to build my project, I can see evidence of the C++ compilation process in eclipse's "console" tab. I also added some #pragma message commands in my source and I see them in the console tab during the compilation. The full console text is as follows:

```
14:08:07 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Motion ****
"C:\\android-ndk-r9c\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
==on==
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: mixed_sample <= cpp_part.cpp
jni/cpp_part.cpp:34:17: note: #pragma message: Compiling, here we go...
jni/cpp_part.cpp:6870:17: note: #pragma message: Compiling, all done.
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libmixed_sample.so
C:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: hidden symbol '__aeabi_atexit' in C:/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a(atexit_arm.o) is referenced by DSO ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libopencv_java.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so

14:08:10 Build Finished (took 2s.617ms)
```

I then wanted to experiment with assorted compilation flags, but became sceptical that they were having any effect. So I tried adding a "-Q" flag ([see here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options)) which should have produced a list of function names as they were compiled, but in the console tab after compilation, I saw no such list. So now I'm suspecting one of several possible screw ups:

1. The compilers output is being displayed somewhere else.
2. The compiler isn't GCC and the flag is being ignored.
3. The particular implementation of GCC doesn't implement -Q
4. I'm adding the flag incorrectly so its not actually being sent to the compiler.

With regard 4, I have a line inside my android.mk which says:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -pg -Winline -Wpedantic -O3 -v -Q
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! Answer was option 4. My flags were being ignored. Turns out I also have an application.mk file which contains "APP_CPPFLAGS := ", if I append the flags on the end of that, then the console tab contains everything I expected to see in the first place.